# Cannot apply CAGradientLayer as UITableView background view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I have a UITableViewController I am trying to apply a gradient background on.

I would like the gradient to be on the entire view and not just the a cell.

I have an extension with a function I am calling in `viewDidLoad`. I am expecting this to be applied and visible behind my `UITableView`

However the background is always white. I set `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear` incase this was just a white layer over my gradient, however it does not appear so as the background is now just black.

**HomeController.swift**

```
   extension HomeController {
        fileprivate func applyBackgroundGradientView() -> Void {
            let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
            let bgView = UIView(frame: frame)
            bgView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientBackgroundView, at: 0)

            tableView.backgroundView = bgView
        }
    }
```

**GradientBackgroundView.swift**

```
class GradientBackgroundView: CAGradientLayer {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupGradientLayer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    fileprivate func setupGradientLayer() -> Void {

        self.colors = ["226320","256c23","39a636","267024"].map({ hex -> CGColor in
            return UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: hex).cgColor
        })

        self.calculatePoints(for: 45)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set gradient on view controller and make tableview clear

Comment: hmmm, so I tried `view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientBackgroundView, at: 0)` and I am getting the same, nothing is being set.

Comment: Have you set the background color of your cell's to `.clear`? You should use the view hierarchy inspect to see if views in front of your background view are occluding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a frame on your `CAGradientLayer`.

If you do not setup the [frame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame), your view will not show.

```
let gradientBackgroundView = GradientBackgroundView()
gradientBackgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientBackgroundView, at: 0)
```